# Google and Facebook login redirect twice at /Account/ExternalLoginCallback MVC - 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I am using google OAuth 2.0 and facebook for login in my asp.net MVC-4 website. I am struggling with a strange issue since quite long. The issue is:

When i click on google login button or facebook login button , i was redirected to google or facebook login page where i enter my login credentials. After that i was redirected to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback Action (which i set as a redirect_uri in facebook and google app settings). **But i was redirected twice to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback**.

I inserted a break point at ExternalLoginCallback action. At first redirection everything goes well and a ExternalLoginConfirmation view show and then again automatically same action (ExternalLoginConfirmation) was called and this time [second time] i got an exception i.e. 404 bad request.

My question is **why i am redirecting twice at /Account/ExternalLoginCallback Action** ????

Please help me i done everything but didn't find any solution and worst thing is i dont know which thing cause the second redirection to /Account/ExternalLoginCallback Action .

Comment: can you post the AccountController code?

Comment: did you figure out why this is happening? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you post the code from the account controller, we might help. However, my thinking is, either you are clicking the button too fast twice, or, there is a duplication of code in the account controller calling Oauth twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it with "Chrome Dev Tool".
Just call "Inspect Element" or Ctrl-Shift-I and check out what is causing the second redirect:
[image]

1) Set "Preserve Log" checkbox and "Disable cache"

2) Show only "Documents" (optional)

3) See that "settings/socias_connections/" is called twice (Ofcourse it would be a different link for your site)

4) See "Initiator" column. So first time it was just a redirect. And for the second time it was initiated by my own script, which tried to remove "#" from the urls. (my silly mistake :)